# How to fix FBSDKLoginKit flutter IOS?

Tags: flutter

error when running the app.

This is for a mac os

```
=== BUILD TARGET firebase_core OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
app/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/FBSDKLoginCompletion.m:136:51: error: property 'isActive' not found on object of type 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate *'
        if ([FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance].isActive) {
                                                      ^
app/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/FBSDKLoginCompletion.m:223:49: error: property 'isActive' not found on object of type 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate *'
      if ([FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance].isActive) {
                                                    ^
    2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 2):

Inconsistent version

1. Delete Podfile.lock in ios directory
2. Add the facebook plugin in your Podfile with same version

   pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.39.1'

   pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.39.1'
3. pod install

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but after spending 6 hours, still unresolved and create more errors not the same as the original one.